# When I run npm install in Laravel project, It shows an error - npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, vue.js, gulp

I installed a fresh copy of Laravel Project. After running command: php artisan preset vue, I ran command npm install which gave an error : -

npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

What Should I do now? I am not able to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem came when they deprecated gulp-util with version 3.0.8 and announced a new version 4.0.0 which is still in alpha stage.So, the move wasn't calculated well and it lead to a much bigger problem because of many plugins dependent on gulp-util-3.0.8.

So now to solve the issue, just change your app.js to below mentioned code

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = Vue;

Vue.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

It will solve your problem for npm install

Comment: I don't see how this is different to the existing https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/app.js and also I don't see how changing app code will change the outcome of an NPM install . Can you explain the reason why this solves the problem ?